# How can i merge or Concatenate data frame having non equal column number in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a project using spark. in some stage i need to merge or concatenate 3 data frame in single data frame. these data frame is coming from spark sql table
i have used union function which already merge column with same number from two table
but i need to  merge unequal column values too . I am confused now 
is there any way to merging or concatenating unequal column based data frame in pyspark kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column with a default value before merging.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

updDf = df2.withColumn('zero_column', lit(0))

df1.union(updDf)
```

Comment: thanks for  your reply. Inside lit() , could i use  value which is coming from a spark sql query ?

Comment: It depends. Can you ask a new question for that with an example to check what you need?